# Is it possible to open a new worksheet with template using a VBA macro on excel

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I wish to copy certain cells and place them into a new worksheet, inside the same workbook, with a template I have previously created. Is it possible to do this?

```
Sub CopyCells()
   Set originalSheet = ActiveSheet
   Set NewSheet = Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveSheet)

   NewSheet.Range("D4:D11").Value = originalSheet.Range("D4:D11").Value
   NewSheet.Range("I4:I8").Value = originalSheet.Range("I4:I9").Value
End Sub
```

With help from others in the forum I can copy and paste the cells I need into a new blank worksheet, but am wondering how to include this template before pasting.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a template sheet, why not copy the template sheet itself. ie.

```
Set NewSheet = Worksheets("Template").Copy(After:= originalSheet)
```

Comment: When running this macro I receive a Type Mismatch error even when nothing is in the cells. Is this a problem in the cell format. Thanks for any help

Comment: Where does the Error occur?

Comment: It seems that you can't set a sheet of a copy, so, you would need to split that. `Worksheets("Template").Copy After:= originalSheet:Set NewSheet = ActiveSheet`